# Captura de inputs de um form com angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Estou tentando criar um objeto contendo todos os inputs de um form para que caso algum esteja checkado, os outros se tornem disable. Existe alguma forma como o

```
document.forms['formParada'].elements['checkboxTipoParada'];
```

Esse é o HTML

```
<label for="tipoParada">Tipo de parada:</label><br>
<form id="formParada" name="tipoParada">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxTipoParada" ng-click="defineParada()">Disponibilidade<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxTipoParada" ng-click="defineParada()">Performance<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxTipoParada" ng-click="defineParada()">Qualidade<br>
</form>
```

E assim esta meu codigo Js

```
$scope.defineParada = function () {
    let checkboxObj = angular.element("formParada").elements;

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxObj.length; i++){
        if (checkboxObj[i].checked == true){
            console.log(checkboxObj[i].value);
        } else {
            checkboxObj[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Fazer isto com angular é fora do padrão e nem faz sentido usá-lo assim, também perde reatividade. Utilize ng-model e faça a manipulação por ele. Dependendo de como quer acionar as modificações pode usar ng-click, ng-change ou um $watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria +/- assim:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope) {
  $scope.valorSelecionado = '';
  $scope.checkboxObj = [
   {nome: 'Disponibilidade', valor: 'vlDisponibilidade', _checked: false},
   {nome: 'Performance', valor: 'vlPerformance', _checked: false},
   {nome: 'Qualidade', valor: 'vlQualidade', _checked: false},
  ];
  
  $scope.podeAtivarCheckbox = function(valor) {
    const itemSelecionado = $scope.checkboxObj.find(item => item._checked);
    if (itemSelecionado && valor !== itemSelecionado.valor) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  /*$scope.defineParada = function () {
    let checkboxObj = angular.element("formParada").elements;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxObj.length; i++){
          if (checkboxObj[i].checked == true){
              console.log(checkboxObj[i].value);
          } else {
              checkboxObj[i].disabled = true;
          }
      }
  };*/
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<label for="tipoParada">Tipo de parada:</label><br>
<form id="formParada" name="tipoParada">
    <label ng-repeat="ckecboxItem in checkboxObj">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-value="ckecboxItem.valor" ng-disabled="!podeAtivarCheckbox(ckecboxItem.valor)" name="checkboxTipoParada" ng-model="ckecboxItem._checked">
      {{ckecboxItem.nome}}
      <br>
    </label>
    {{valorSelecionado}}
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Ótimo, era exatamente o que eu queria fazer, muito obrigado pela ajuda!